# Gaussian white noise evaluated at a function: $\xi(f[t])$

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

A major property of Gaussian white noise $\xi(t)$ is its correlation function:
$$ \langle \xi(t)\xi(t+\tau) \rangle = \Gamma \delta(\tau).$$
From this, it seems possible to derive the form of white noise evaluated at $\alpha t$:
$$\langle \xi(\alpha t)\xi (\alpha[t+\tau]) \rangle = \Gamma \delta(\alpha \tau)$$
Using the property $\delta(\alpha \tau) = \delta(\tau)/\alpha$ of the delta function, we can find:
$$ \langle \alpha^{-1/2}\xi(\alpha t)\alpha^{-1/2}\xi (\alpha[t+\tau]) \rangle = \langle \xi(t)\xi(t+\tau)\rangle.$$
This suggests that we have the identity
$$ \xi(t) = \alpha^{-1/2} \xi(\alpha t). $$
That is, white noise at argument $\alpha t$ is equivalent to $\sqrt{\alpha}$ times white noise at argument $t$.

**Question:**

Is it possible to generalize this argument somehow to find a relation between $\xi(t)$ and white noise of a function? For example, can we relate
$$ \xi\big(f(t)\big)$$
somehow to just $\xi(t)$?

Answer (score 2):

When $f$ is a diffeomorphism $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ there is no problem defining the composition $\xi\circ f$. White noise $\xi$ is a random Schwartz distribution in $\mathscr{S}'(\mathbb{R})\subset\mathscr{D}'(\mathbb{R})$. The composition can be done pointwise (for each realization of $\xi$) using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)#Composition_with_a_smooth_function
If $f$ and its inverse have derivatives that grow at most polynomially at infinity then the composition $\xi\circ f$ stays in the space of temperate distributions $\mathscr{S}'(\mathbb{R})$.

If you want more complicated maps $f$, then some care is required. For an example, see this article about showing conformal invariance (not just scale invariance as you derived correctly) of white noise:

T. Hida, Takeyuki, I. Kubo, H. Nomoto and H. Yoshizawa, ["On projective invariance of Brownian motion"](https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/kyotoms1965/4/3/4_3_595/_article/-char/ja/),
Publ. Res. Inst. Math. Sci. Ser. A 4, 595–609 (1969).